# shouldn't keep textarea data?

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a *textarea* inside a *form*:

```
<form action="#" id="container">
  <textarea id="txt" cols="100" rows="5">Good bye</textarea>
</form>
```

All I want is to replace this *form* by a *div*:

```
$("#container").replaceWith(function() {
    return "<div>" + $(this).html() + "</div>";
});
```

That works without any problem, but if I before to use the *replaceWith* method change the textarea value:

```
$("#txt").val("hello world");
```

The final content is a *textarea* inside the *div* with the "Good bye" text, not the "hello world" as expected. You have a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/kRGqR/1/).

Why is this happening? How can I replace the *form* by a *div* preserving textarea contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This works:](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/kRGqR/7/)

```
$("#txt").val("hello world");
$("#container").replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<div />').append($(this).contents());
});
```

The issue come with serializing the html with `.html()`. It's much better to work in terms of DOM Nodes. This'll also preserve event handlers.

---

Here's another way:

```
$('#container').wrapInner('<div/>').children().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.val()` is changing the value of the textarea (meaning the data sent when form is submitted), not necessarily its inner text/HTML.. to do so use `.html()` instead:

```
$("#txt").html("hello world");
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRGqR/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, (use `.html()` instead) (`html()` inserts value INSIDE that textarea, `.val()` doesn't)

http://jsfiddle.net/kRGqR/5/